# Finding sibling tag in BeautifulSoup with no attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Sorry, kind of a beginner question about BeatifulSoup, but I can't find the answer.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to scrape  HTML tags without attributes.

Here's the section of code.

```
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
 <td>
  No-Lobbying List
 </td>
 <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
  <td rowspan="2" valign="top">
   6/24/2019
  </td>
  <td>
   <a href="document.cfm?id=322577" target="_blank">
    Brian Manley, Chief of Police, Austin Police Department
   </a>
   <a href="document.cfm?id=322577" target="_blank">
    <img alt="Click here to download the PDF document" border="0"     height="16"     src="https://assets.austintexas.gov/edims/images/pdf_icon.gif"     width="16"/>
   </a>
  </td>
  <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
   <td>
    Preliminary 2018 Annual Crime Report - Executive Summary
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tr>
</tr>
```

How can I navigate to the  tag with the text "Preliminary 2018 Annual Crime Report - Executive Summary"?

I have tried moving from a  with an attribute and using .next_sibling, but I've failed miserable.

Thank you.

```
trgrewy = soup.findAll('tr', {'bgcolor':'#efefef'}) #the cells alternate colors
trwhite = soup.findAll('tr', {'bgcolor':'#ffffff'}) 
trs = trgrewy + trwhite #merge them into a list
for item in trs:
    mdate = item.find('td', {'rowspan':'2'}) #find if it's today's date
    if mdate:
        datetime_object = datetime.strptime(mdate.text, '%m/%d/%Y')
        if datetime_object.date() == now.date():
            sender = item.find('a').text
            pdf = item.find('a')['href']
            link = baseurl + pdf
            title = item.findAll('td')[2] #this is where i've failed
```

Comment: you have to read documentation for BeautifuSoup. it has not only find() and findAll() but also `parent()`, `child()`, `sibling()`, etc. Youc also get all tags and use index and get last element - ie. td[-1] to get your "Preliminary 2018 Annual Crime Report - Executive Summary"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors:

```
data = '''
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
 <td>
  No-Lobbying List
 </td>
 <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
  <td rowspan="2" valign="top">
   6/24/2019
  </td>
  <td>
   <a href="document.cfm?id=322577" target="_blank">
    Brian Manley, Chief of Police, Austin Police Department
   </a>
   <a href="document.cfm?id=322577" target="_blank">
    <img alt="Click here to download the PDF document" border="0"     height="16"     src="https://assets.austintexas.gov/edims/images/pdf_icon.gif"     width="16"/>
   </a>
  </td>
  <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
   <td>
    Preliminary 2018 Annual Crime Report - Executive Summary
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tr>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

# This will find date
print(soup.select_one('td[rowspan="2"]').get_text(strip=True))

# This will find next row after the row with date
print(soup.select_one('tr:has(td[rowspan="2"]) + tr').get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
6/24/2019
Preliminary 2018 Annual Crime Report - Executive Summary
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```py
page = BeautifulSoup(HTML_TEXT)

text = page.find('td').findAll(text=True, recursive=False)

for i in text:
    print i
```